# Injective Bijective Surjective

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Determine if each one of the following functions $f : A \rightarrow B$ is injective (one–to–one), surjective (onto), bijective, or none of these:

How could these be solved? I'm very confused by the notation at the end in particular. I know what null set and power sets are but the notation at the end with the f() is tricking me.

1. $A\neq \emptyset,B=\mathcal{P} (A),f(a)=\{a\}$.
2. $A = B = \mathcal{P}({a,b,c,d}), f(X) = X$.
3. $A = B = \mathcal{P}({a,b,c,d}), f(X) = X \bigcup \{a,b\}$.
4. $A = B = \mathcal{P}({a,b,c,d}), f(X) = X \bigcap \{a,b\}$.

Comment: What is A with the strike through in #1?

Comment: Try proving that if f: A --> A and A is a finite set then f is injective if and only if f is surjective

Answer (score 0):

These define 4 functions, each named $f$, on the pattern $f:A\to B$, i.e. here $A$ denotes the domain and $B$ the codomain (i.e. the set of possible values) of function $f$.

1. The domain of our first function $f$ is any nonempty set $A$, the codomain is its power set, and $f$ maps an element $a$ to its one-element set $\{a\}$ in the powerset. 
   This function is injective and not surjective, hence neither bijective.
2. The second function is the identity function ($f(X)=X$) on the 16 element power set $P(\{a,b,c,d\})$. It is bijective.

Can you go on with the other ones?

Comment: So what is in the power set for the first one? Just the null and {a} right?

Comment: The power set of set $A$ is the set of all subsets of $A$. If $A$ contains only one element, then, yes, $P(A)$ contains only these two elements. But $A$ can be a bigger set, and then $P(A)$ contains more subsets.

Comment: could I get a full solution to at least the first two? I need to see how they are done so I can understand it a bit better.

Comment: Rewrite this notation to the one you prefer. (E.g. I like to denote a function, for example for 1., as $f:a\mapsto \{a\}$ - which is basically what's written on the first line.)

Comment: why is the second one bijective? A and B will contain the same set of elements and there will be mapping to a unique B for each A.

Comment: and so for the first one the power set of A only contains {a} and not the null element is that correct?

Comment: @Berci I think that even if $|A|=1$, the first function is not surjective. This is because there is no $a \in A$ such that $f(a)=\emptyset$.

Comment: @user181415 The powerset of $A$ always contains $\emptyset$ as element (as $\emptyset$ is always a subset of $A$), but the *image* (or *range*) of $f$ consists of exactly the one element subsets of $A$, and this is not the whole codomain (as e.g. $\emptyset$ is certainly missing), so this $f$ for 1. is not surjective. For 2., the function $f$ given is the *identity* $X\mapsto X$ from a powerset to itself. Its bijective, as any $X\in P(\{a,b,c,d\})$ will be an image of exactly one element in the domain, namely itself.

Answer (score 0):

1. $A\neq \emptyset,B=\mathcal{P} (A),f(a)=\{a\}$.
   If $|A|=1$ then $f$ is injective by definition. Assume $|A|>1, \ a\in A,b\in 
    A$ and $a\neq b$. Then $f(a)=\{a\}\neq \{b\}=f(b)$, so $f$ is injective. 
   Power set of any set $S$ satisfy [following equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set#Properties):
   $$ |\mathcal{P}(S)|=2^{|S|}$$
   For example $|\{a,b,c,d\}|=4$ and $|\mathcal{P}(\{a,b,c,d\})|=2^4=16$.
   Now $f(A)=\{\{a\}:a\in A\}$ - $f(A)$ is obtained by putting every element 
   $a\in A$ to unique set $\{a\}\in \mathcal{P}(A)$. Therefore $|A|=|f(A)|$. 
   But $A\neq \emptyset$ so $1\le |A|<2^{|A|}=|\mathcal{P}(A)|=B$. Inequality 
   $|f(A)|<|B|$ means, that $f$ is not suriection, neither bijection (not even 
   when $|A|=1$!).
2. $A = B = \mathcal{P}(\{a,b,c,d\}), f(X) = X$. This function could be redefined as follow:
   $$f:\mathcal{P}(\{a,b,c,d\})\ni X \mapsto X \in \mathcal{P}(\{a,b,c,d\})$$
   This kind of function is called [identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function#Definition), and it is injective and surjective (thus bijective).

Try to prove that functions (3.) and (4.) are not injective, neither surjective. Observe that in both cases domain $\mathcal{P}(\{a,b,c,d\})$ is the same as codomain.

Sidenote: nullset is subset of any set $S$, so in particular $\emptyset \subset\mathcal{P}(S)$.